# Nextjs 13 build : location is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have set up an authentication checking via **localstorage** on a nextjs app like so :

```js
'use client'

const router = useRouter();
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<string | null>(null);

const checkAuth = () => {
    return localStorage.getItem('auth');
}

useEffect(() => {
        setAuth(checkAuth());
    }, []);

if (!auth) {
        router.push('/admin/login');
        return;
    }

return <div>...</div>
```

The issue is that when I build the project I get the following error :
**ReferenceError: location is not defined
at AdminPage (admin/page.tsx:260:16)**

Note that I have also tried checking **if the window object is undefined** before accessing localstorage but the error is still the same.
Is there another way to check the auth item from localstorage to prevent unconnected users from accessing this page and redirect them to the login page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use “use client” directive for client side components.

Put `"use client"` as the first line in the file containing this component.

Comment: I've already done it. I just forgot to put it here in the post.

Comment: Where are you using location?

Comment: That's the problem, I am not using it. It appears when I use next build.

Comment: Please share minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

I've came a cross the same issue and indeed the strange thing is that it's a client component...

The "location" (aka useRouter) is accesable from the document or window, but on "build" you are in let's say the node, and in node environment you don't have access to the location. Same thing for the localStorage.

Didn't manage to find a explanation for this behavior but a work around is to put your localStorage and also the router.push in a useEffect hook.

GL